# CSS Styling how to show specific bullets in one line

Tags: html, css

In the following example I'd like to have items 2 and 3 to appear side-by-side and the rest to remain as a stacked unordered list. How to do this in css?

```html
<li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textone</li>
<li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>texttwo</li>
<li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textthree</li>
<li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textfour</li>
```

this code shows like this below.

textone

texttwo

textthree

textfour

But I want to show this as this image below. How to do this in CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple float and a margin should do it.

```css
.stack {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textone</li>
<li class="stack"><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>texttwo</li>
<li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textthree</li>
<li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textfour</li>
```

Comment: FWIW: There's no need to add an extra element: http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/KamQga

Answer (score 1):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can use a *wrapping* `flexbox`:

1. Each flex item will have 100% `flex-basis`
2. The second and third items will have *auto* `flex-basis`

This will make 2 and 3 to come in the same line - see demo below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul > li {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
ul > li:nth-child(2), ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ul>
  <li>textone</li>
  <li>texttwo</li>
  <li>textthree</li>
  <li>textfour</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  /* removing bullet */
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  /* adding bullet as pseudoelement's content */
  content: "• ";
}

li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(3) {
  /* display item as inline or inline-block */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textone</li>
  <li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>texttwo</li>
  <li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textthree</li>
  <li><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>textfour</li>
</ul>
```